# Best way to serialize a byte[] to a JSON-file

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm working with JSON-files and serializing. Well, so far I'm fine.
Now, I have a question, I am signing data (bytes) with the RSA-class, so actually, I made a wrapper, but this is similar though.
It returns a byte[] and now I want to serialize this byte[] to a JSON-file, where also other normals strings are in. But I have no idea how to start.

The signature must be within this JSON-document.
My beginning was to convert the byte[] to a string and after that convert it back again.

```
public static string ConvertToString(byte[] input)
{
     System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
     return enc.GetString(input);
}
```

So, well I call it like that:

```
string signature = Converter.ConvertToString(new RsaSignature(PrivateKey).SignData(data));
```

So, this signs the given data and then should convert the returned **byte[]** to a string in order to serialize it, because, as I said, the rest of the JSON contains only strings.

Is there maybe a way to serialize the byte[] directly to it? Or how should I manage this.

Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Bytes are not text.  Are you asking for Bas64?

Comment: I already thought about Base64. How far would this work or make sense in my case?

Comment: You can use base64 to serialize arbitrary bytes to text.

Comment: Ah, well sounds good. And then I can reverse this again in order to read it out, I think.
Well, so Base64 seems to be the solution then.
You can write an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for base64, which allows you to serialize arbitrary bytes to text.

Comment: Thanks you! I think this is the solution ;)
btw: Very high reputation :)

I will accept as soon as it is possible (some minutes).